# responsive,dynamic row of divs with text at 90 degrees

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design

I am trying to obtain this look.

[image: wireframe shot 1]

but have only been able to achieve this with a transform (which I think is the problem).  can't find other ways of having rotated text...

[image: browser shot 1]

```
<div class='header-container' layout='row' layout-align='center'>

    <div flex='70' class='create-header' layout='row' layout-align='center'>
        <div ng-repeat='member in members' layout-fill layout='row' layout-align='start'>
            <div flex class='table-header'>{{member.name}}  {{member.instrument1}}</div>
            <div ng-hide="member.instrument2 == ''"class='table-header'>{{member.name}}  {{member.instrument2}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

div.table-header {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*margin-right: 40px;*/
    /*width: 13px;*/
}
```

Comment: In this [blog post](https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/) they've mentioned how to rotate text but I also have a problem with the responsive behaviour of the rotated text. Please have a look at my current [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/sgfvf2gb/). It's the demo from css tricks with other rotation and manually changed translation (not calculated). But if you narrow down the result you'll see that the heading will be missaligned.

Comment: yes, I went through that blog post as well, but when I saw the translate rule I shifted away.  Didn't seem applicable for me since my # columns is dynamic.  I suspect the transform is the problem, because there is no reason for the spacing between the divs other than that's where the div "was" before transformation....I could be wrong though

Comment: I think that should also work for dynamic columns. Have you tried to add a height to the header? That could help. I've updated my fiddle and it seems to work now. It's also important to use the `modernizer` script. Not sure why but with-out it wasn't working in FF.

Comment: thanks Wolf, you might be right.  I'll post my success when it comes!

Answer (score 0):

these combinations of edits gave me an acceptable result - a little tweaking so it looks right on larger screens to come...the key was setting the width on the div to be approximately the width of the smallest box below it.

```
<div flex='70' class='create-header' layout='row' layout-align='center'>
        <div ng-repeat='member in members' flex layout='row' layout-align='start'>
            <div flex class='table-header'>{{member.name}}-{{member.instrument1}}</div>
            <div flex ng-hide="member.instrument2 == ''"class='table-header'>{{member.name}}-{{member.instrument2}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

div.table-header {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*height: 140px;*/
    /*margin-right: 40px;*/
    width: 20px;
}
```